# Unable to SSH into new Lightsail instance created from snapshot

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I have a Lightsail instance with a snapshot. After creating a new instance using that snapshot, I am unable to connect via ssh. I am still able to connect via ssh to my original instance.

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you fix it?

Comment: Try clearing out your known_hosts file in your ssh folder:
1) cd into .ssh folder
2) run command: # > known_hosts

Comment: It doesn't affect, if you mean locally I've cleared it and have the same problem, I just get rejected because the Lightsail instance's port 22 is closed despite the aws UI saying it's open

Comment: Sounds like you figured it out.

Comment: I didn't, still dealing with it, I can't figure it out

Comment: Does the in browser SSH work correctly?